# BEM: Is it okay to use two element classes on one child?

Tags: bem

Example:

```
<div class="pageProduct">
  <div class="pageProduct__section pageProduct__secondChildClass"></div>
  <div class="pageProduct__section></div>
  <div class="pageProduct__section></div>
  <div class="pageProduct__section></div>
</div>
```

I don't want to use a modifier and I'm not sure if this syntax is okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, it's called [mix](https://en.bem.info/methodology/key-concepts/#mix). There also can be a mix of a block and an element on the same DOM node.

Comment: What about a block and an element _of the same block_ on the same DOM node? I've seen that done recently, but feels wrong to me?